# Retrieve values from multiple tables in sql with case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, **relations** and **users**

As usual, **relations** has two id fields that correlate certain **users** in a certain context.
What I would need is to retrieve information from both this tables in one query following a certain logic explicit below:

### `relations            users                            .`

`id1 id2 situation              id   name    other_fields_________________________`
`1    3    "inf"                1    "Rich"                                      .`
`5    2    "inf"                2    "Joan"                                      .`
`5    1    "inf"                3    "Rito"                                      .`
`4    2    "inf"                4    "Nena"                                      .`
`5    4    "inf"                5    "Sini"                                      .`

I need to ***join*** both tables on the correct id from ***users***  **AND** (id1 or id2) from ***relations***. So, If I would have an id **5**, I would fetch both tables and get everything from users where the id is **7**!

This is:

-> I have the id 1. What I want to retrieve:
`id2: 3, situation: "inf", name: "Rito"` 
`id1: 5, situation: "inf", name:"Sini"`
(I started checking the partners of id 1 in relations and got their information, joined by **users.id = relations.id1 or relations.id2** accordingly to the position of my id (1).

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple join.

```
SELECT r.id2, r.situation, u2.name, r.id1, r.situation, u1.name
FROM users u1, users u2, relations r
WHERE u1.id = r.id1
AND u2.id = r.id2
AND u1.id = 1
```

Change the last line with the targeted ID

Comment: this doesn't work. I don't know if the id I want is always in id1. I need case because I need to check which of **id1** or **id2** is equal to the id I want. No, it's not a simple join.

Comment: sorry but I don't get what you want to do